# Braintree dropinUI not working with Paypal "Client Error"

Tags: swift, paypal, paypal-sandbox, braintree

I am using Braintree to process credit cards and PayPal payments. I am using the drop-in UI. However, whenever I click on the PayPal option, it closes the payment menu and kicks back the error below.

```
ERROR SHOWING DROP IN: Optional(Error Domain=com.braintreepayments.BTHTTPErrorDomain Code=2 "client error" UserInfo={com.braintreepayments.BTHTTPURLResponseKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x282f79b00> { URL: https://api.sandbox.braintreegateway.com:443/merchants/<MERCHANTID>/client_api/v1/paypal_hermes/setup_billing_agreement } { Status Code: 422, Headers {
    "Cache-Control" =     (
        "no-cache"
    );
    "Content-Encoding" =     (
        gzip
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Sun, 22 Dec 2019 01:56:11 GMT"
    );
    "Strict-Transport-Security" =     (
        "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
    );
    "Transfer-Encoding" =     (
        Identity
    );
    Vary =     (
        "Accept-Encoding, Origin"
    );
    "content-security-policy" =     (
        "frame-ancestors 'self'"
    );
    "x-broxyid" =     (
        "29ed0050-9b28-045e-d3a1-1a1795467ca8f366"
    );
    "x-content-type-options" =     (
        nosniff
    );
    "x-frame-options" =     (
        SAMEORIGIN
    );
    "x-pod-name" =     (
        "cloud-ingress-7b97c4466-6jvh8"
    );
    "x-request-id" =     (
        "29ed0050-9b28-045e-d3a1-1a1795467ca8f366"
    );
    "x-runtime" =     (
        "0.423936"
    );
    "x-xss-protection" =     (
        "1; mode=block"
    );
} }, NSLocalizedFailureReason=client error, com.braintreepayments.BTHTTPJSONResponseBodyKey=<BTJSON:0x282e8c480 value:{
    error =     {
        debugId = 6abb1c4326a9e;
        errorMessage = "Client Authentication failed";
        errorName = "invalid_client";
        paypalHttpStatus = 401;
    };
}>})
ERROR LOCAL: Optional("The operation couldn’t be completed. client error")
```

Below is the code for my payment methods. I have done the setup in app delegate correctly and my server is returning a client token correctly.

```
@IBAction func paypalButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        print("GETTING CLIENT TOKEN")
        let payPalDriver = BTPayPalDriver(apiClient: braintreeClient!)
        payPalDriver.viewControllerPresentingDelegate = self
        payPalDriver.appSwitchDelegate = self

        let request = BTPayPalRequest(amount: "2.32")
        request.currencyCode = "USD"
        request.billingAgreementDescription = "BILLING AGGREEMENT??"

        //Retrieving Client Token from server
        let ref = db.collection("users").document(self.userUID).getDocument { (snap, err) in
            if err != nil {
                print("ERROR GETTING CUSTOMER ID FOR BRAINTREE")
            } else {
                var res = snap!.data()!["BTID"]! as! [String:Any]
                print(res["customerID"])

                var dataSend = ["customerID" : res["customerID"]]

                self.functions.httpsCallable("createToken").call(dataSend) { (response, err) in
                    if err != nil {
                        print("Error: \(err?.localizedDescription))")
                    } else {
                        var token = response?.data as! String
                        print("RESPONSE: \(response?.data)")
                        self.braintreeClient = BTAPIClient(authorization: token)
                        self.showDropIn(clientToken: token)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func showDropIn(clientToken: String) {
        let request = BTDropInRequest()

        let dropIn = BTDropInController(authorization: clientToken, request: request) { (controller, result, err) in
            if err != nil {
                print("ERROR SHOWING DROP IN: \(err)")
                print("ERROR LOCAL: \(err?.localizedDescription)")
            } else if (result?.isCancelled == true) {
                print("CANCELLED")
            } else if let result = result {
                print(result.paymentMethod)
            }
            controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        self.present(dropIn!, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: First thing I would test is the URL you used under URL Schemes. Will you try to copy and paste that into your Mobile Safari and see what it does?